# Mudar caption do Carousel no iphone

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, css3, carousel

Tenho um site desenvolvido com Bootstrap que possui um carrousel `<div class="carousel-inner">`.

Quero que no iPhone, a *caption* `<div class="carousel-caption">` diminua, de modo que apareça mais a imagem.
Nos outros dispositivos funciona bem, somente no iPhone que a *caption* fica totalmente em cima da imagem.

Como resolver?

Comment: Tem um link pro site ou o html da página do carousel com o css respectivo?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você esteja falando de **[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**,

Acho que essa questão tem a ver com a dimensão da tela, faça um teste usando outro browser no iphone, para ver se continua a mesma coisa;

Infelizmente eu não sei de cabeça as dimensões exatas do Iphone, cabe a você pesquisar (depende da versão);  Mas com media queries, você consegue configurar o css.

Precisa de um pouco de tratamento, mas acho que seria uma coisa assim:

```
/*Muito pequeno(<768px)*/
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
  .carousel-caption {position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
font-size: 20px;
}
/*Pequeno (≥768px)*/  
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
      .carousel-caption {position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
font-size: 40px;
}
/*Médio (≥992px)*/    
@media only screen and (max-width:992px){
     .carousel-caption {position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
font-size: 60px;
}
/*Grande (≥1200px)*/
@media only screen and (max-width:1200px){
      .carousel-caption {position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
font-size: 80px;
}
}
```